# how to define event to javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I want to desgin drag and drop tool bar.I am new to javascript/jquery.

So i don't know how to define drag and drop , how to handle drag event and drop event.

Comment: Have you tried to Google "html5 drag&drop api"?

Comment: Check [this link](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) for an example and [this one](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/) for the complete JQuery UI Draggable documentation.

Comment: @jehna1 yes i have tried .. but i need more detail info like how to define event and how to write event